# Can Webpack easily expose the default class of a module rather than the module itself?

Tags: javascript, webpack, fusioncharts

I am trying to expose a module via Webpack (in this case, FusionCharts) to the global scope so that it can be accessed directly by an in-page script. I can get almost all of the way, but I haven't been able to expose the `FusionCharts` class directly; instead I get the Module itself, with `default: class FusionCharts` in it.

My relevant Webpack configuration looks like this:

```
...
module: {
    rules: [
        ...,
        { test: /core\/index\.js$/, use: ['expose-loader?FusionCharts'] }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        ...,
        FusionCharts: ['fusioncharts/core', 'default']
    })
],
...
```

I then have a `charts.js` file that, in a simple example, looks like:

```
import Column2D from 'fusioncharts/viz/column2d';
FusionCharts.addDep(Column2D);
```

Webpack correctly builds the `charts.js` file to include the FusionCharts library, and the script on the page can see the `FusionCharts` variable, but it is the Module rather than the class.

For example, the page might have:

```
<script src="/assets/charts.js"></script>
...
<script>
    $(function() {
        // would output "FusionCharts: Module"
        console.log(FusionCharts);

        // would output "class FusionCharts" (which is what I am after)
        console.log(FusionCharts.default);
    });
</script>
```

Is it possible to directly expose the class like this? I thought maybe the `expose-loader` had a way to automatically dereference the default the way the `ProvidePlugin` does, but if so, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing FusionCharts into your js file, you need to import the FusionCharts module in order to access all FusionCharts properties and items, for reference check this link - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts#parameters-1

Also, check this sample for details - https://www.dropbox.com/s/4v5xqyxl66djr6y/fc%203.13.zip?dl=0